# List of lists - Multi level

Tags: java, list, data-structures, collections

I have the following structure :

```
  public class User ...
  <User> location;
  <List<User>> program;
  List<List<User>>> project;
  List<List<List<User>>>> team;
```

The above structure means User-->Locations-->Program --> Project --> Team .In other words each user belongs to mutlipple locations.In each location he is linked to several programs. Each such program has muliple projects.Each project is linked to several teams.

Now my question is there any other alternative to this data structure.I think the above structure is no at all efficient and retrieving values would be tedious. Hence suggest a suitable yet an efficient alternative.

Comment: Its Java, use classes

Comment: My first question is: how a User can be a Program? If you create specific objects for each purpose, this could be better and easier to maintain

Comment: <User> location; <List<User>> program; wouldn't be this two properties enough to build nested menu and based on nested level u can decide if it's project or team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bad design.

If a program contains a `List` of `User`s, define a `Program` class that has a `List<User>` instance variable. Instead of `List<User> program;`, you'd have a `Program program;`.

If a project contains a `List` of programs, define a `Project` class that has a `List<Program>` instance variable. Instead of `List<List<User>>> project;`, you'd have a `Project project;`.

If a team contains a `List` of projects, define a `Team` class that has a `List<Project>` instance variable. Instead of `List<List<List<User>>>> team;`, you'd have a `Team team;`.